# Cannot view or Read advertisement data of a Beacon in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, ibeacon

I currently have a Estimote beacon and I am using wireshark on Ubuntu. A USB dongle which can receive BLE data is connected to my laptop.  When I start the Bluetooth 0 on wireshark it does not show any data packets. What might be the reason that I cannot see any data packets even though the beacon is placed close by to the laptop. I followed this link till the "sudo wireshark" command.

http://www.orangenarwhals.com/?p=887